# El servidor MySQL no autorizó su acceso

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Ya cambie la carpeta config.in.php la copie  tambien cambie los puerto en XAMMP de apache y mysql no se que hacer[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Estas usando XAMPP?

Answer (score 1):

Ingresar a mysql:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Seleccionar la base de datos mysql:

```
use mysql;
```

Ejecutar las siguientes sentencias:

```
ALTER USER 'userdb'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'userdbpassword';
ALTER USER 'userdb'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'userdbpassword';
```

Reemplazar "userdb" por el usuario de de conexión a la base de datos, y reemplazar "userdbpassword" por la clave del usuario de conexión a la base de datos.

Por último, salir de mysql y realizar las pruebas de conexión con phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

Con XAMMP no hay que configurar nada para un primer acceso, después de instalarlo y arrancar el servidor debes de poder tener acceso, prueba a reinstalarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```
127.0.0.1/phpMyAdmin
```

A mi también me ocurría eso pero una vez que entre así ya me permitía el acceso.